# Click agmMarker in Protractor Tests

Tags: javascript, protractor, google-maps-markers

I am rendering location on google maps using agmMarker component. When I am using protractor to test , how can I click a specific agmMarker on the map?

I am unable to figure the exact clickable element within the DOM when I look at the html source.

Comment: please add your current code

Comment: This does not have enough information to be an answerable question. I agree that code might help as well as a snippet of the DOM with the marker.